# gnuplot back of 3d surface

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

I find that gnuplot doesn't use a contrasting color for the back of my 3D surface.  I have copied the code for an example from the gnuplot site and it still doesn't work, so I guess the problem is with my configuration.  "set hidden3d back offset 1"  I am running Debian Wheezy; my terminal is set to wxt; gnuplot is 4.6 (the latest in the form of a Debian package.)  I could try going to gnuplot 5, but I'd like to hear if anyone else has had this problem.
This code is from [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/surface2.html) -- the 7th example.

```
set dummy u,v
set key bmargin center horizontal Right noreverse enhanced autotitles nobox
set parametric
set view 50, 30, 1, 1
set isosamples 40, 20
set hidden3d back offset 1 trianglepattern 3 undefined 1 altdiagonal bentover
set ticslevel 0
set title "Parametric Shell (clipped to limited z range)" 
set urange [ 0.00000 : 6.28319 ] noreverse nowriteback
set vrange [ 0.00000 : 6.28319 ] noreverse nowriteback
set zrange [ -3.00000 : 1.50000 ] noreverse nowriteback
splot cos(u)*u*(1+cos(v)/2),sin(v)*u/2,sin(u)*u*(1+cos(v)/2)
```

The result shown has 2 colors, but when I use it, I get only 1 (red).

Comment: This is a bug in version 4.6. patchlevel 0 (which is what Wheezy has), and is fixed at least since 4.6 patchlevel 3. So you could try the [4.6.6 backport](https://packages.debian.org/en/wheezy-backports/gnuplot).

Comment: Thank you, @Christoph -- that worked.  We give up the wxt terminal in 4.6.6, which is a shame, since it is much faster than x11.

Comment: Who gives up the wxt terminal?

Comment: @Christoph, when installing, I find this floating in the output stream:   "We stop to provide wxt-terminal because wxwidgets 3.0 is not compatible
  with gnuplot [1], [2]. wxt-terminal will be enabled again if the bug
  will be fixed.
  [1] https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1401
  [2] https://bugs.debian.org/750045
 -- Anton Gladky <gladk@debian.org>  Wed, 04 Jun 2014 22:46:22 +0200